# Python script returning KafkaTimeoutError: Failed to update metadata after 60.0 secs

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-kafka

deployed a kafka bitnami on aws ec2. https://bitnami.com/stack/kafka/cloud

I opened up ports 9092 on my sec groups and was able to perform the steps in the bitnami document.

Right now, I am writing a simple python script from my client notebook to do produce messages to my Kafka on ec2. My code is as below

```
from time import sleep
from json import dumps
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)


# produce json messages
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['xxxxxx:9092'], value_serializer=lambda m: json.dumps(m).encode('ascii'))
producer.send('test', {'key': 'value'})
producer.flush()
```

However, i keep hitting a

`kafka.errors.KafkaTimeoutError: KafkaTimeoutError: Failed to update metadata after 60.0 secs.`

checking the logs @ /opt/bitnami/kafka/logs/server.log and I notice that

`Failed authentication with /202.127.74.162 (Unexpected Kafka request of type METADATA during SASL handshake.) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)`

I have already opened up the ports on my AWS as well. any help?

Additional info:

this is my server.conf

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# see kafka.server.KafkaConfig for additional details and defaults

############################# Server Basics #############################

# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
broker.id=-1

############################# Socket Server Settings #############################

# The address the socket server listens on. It will get the value returned from 
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName() if not configured.
#   FORMAT:
listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://:9092
#   EXAMPLE:
#     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
#listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092

# Hostname and port the broker will advertise to producers and consumers. If not set, 
# it uses the value for "listeners" if configured.  Otherwise, it will use the value
# returned from java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().
advertised.listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://:9092

# Maps listener names to security protocols, the default is for them to be the same. See the config documentation for more details
#listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL

# The number of threads that the server uses for receiving requests from the network and sending responses to the network
num.network.threads=3

# The number of threads that the server uses for processing requests, which may include disk I/O
num.io.threads=8

# The send buffer (SO_SNDBUF) used by the socket server
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400

# The receive buffer (SO_RCVBUF) used by the socket server
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400

# The maximum size of a request that the socket server will accept (protection against OOM)
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600


############################# Log Basics #############################

# A comma separated list of directories under which to store log files
log.dirs=/opt/bitnami/kafka/data

# The default number of log partitions per topic. More partitions allow greater
# parallelism for consumption, but this will also result in more files across
# the brokers.
num.partitions=1

# The number of threads per data directory to be used for log recovery at startup and flushing at shutdown.
# This value is recommended to be increased for installations with data dirs located in RAID array.
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

############################# Internal Topic Settings  #############################
# The replication factor for the group metadata internal topics "__consumer_offsets" and "__transaction_state"
# For anything other than development testing, a value greater than 1 is recommended for to ensure availability such as 3.
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1

############################# Log Flush Policy #############################

# Messages are immediately written to the filesystem but by default we only fsync() to sync
# the OS cache lazily. The following configurations control the flush of data to disk.
# There are a few important trade-offs here:
#    1. Durability: Unflushed data may be lost if you are not using replication.
#    2. Latency: Very large flush intervals may lead to latency spikes when the flush does occur as there will be a lot of data to flush.
#    3. Throughput: The flush is generally the most expensive operation, and a small flush interval may lead to excessive seeks.
# The settings below allow one to configure the flush policy to flush data after a period of time or
# every N messages (or both). This can be done globally and overridden on a per-topic basis.

# The number of messages to accept before forcing a flush of data to disk
#log.flush.interval.messages=10000

# The maximum amount of time a message can sit in a log before we force a flush
#log.flush.interval.ms=1000

############################# Log Retention Policy #############################

# The following configurations control the disposal of log segments. The policy can
# be set to delete segments after a period of time, or after a given size has accumulated.
# A segment will be deleted whenever *either* of these criteria are met. Deletion always happens
# from the end of the log.

# The minimum age of a log file to be eligible for deletion due to age
log.retention.hours=168

# A size-based retention policy for logs. Segments are pruned from the log unless the remaining
# segments drop below log.retention.bytes. Functions independently of log.retention.hours.
#log.retention.bytes=1073741824

# The maximum size of a log segment file. When this size is reached a new log segment will be created.
log.segment.bytes=1073741824

# The interval at which log segments are checked to see if they can be deleted according
# to the retention policies
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

############################# Zookeeper #############################

# Zookeeper connection string (see zookeeper docs for details).
# This is a comma separated host:port pairs, each corresponding to a zk
# server. e.g. "127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1:3001,127.0.0.1:3002".
# You can also append an optional chroot string to the urls to specify the
# root directory for all kafka znodes.
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181

# Timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000


############################# Group Coordinator Settings #############################

# The following configuration specifies the time, in milliseconds, that the GroupCoordinator will delay the initial consumer rebalance.
# The rebalance will be further delayed by the value of group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms as new members join the group, up to a maximum of max.poll.interval.ms.
# The default value for this is 3 seconds.
# We override this to 0 here as it makes for a better out-of-the-box experience for development and testing.
# However, in production environments the default value of 3 seconds is more suitable as this will help to avoid unnecessary, and potentially expensive, rebalances during application startup.
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN

sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN

security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
```

this is my producer properties:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
# see org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig for more details

############################# Producer Basics #############################

# list of brokers used for bootstrapping knowledge about the rest of the cluster
# format: host1:port1,host2:port2 ...
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

# specify the compression codec for all data generated: none, gzip, snappy, lz4, zstd
compression.type=none

# name of the partitioner class for partitioning events; default partition spreads data randomly
#partitioner.class=

# the maximum amount of time the client will wait for the response of a request
#request.timeout.ms=

# how long `KafkaProducer.send` and `KafkaProducer.partitionsFor` will block for
#max.block.ms=

# the producer will wait for up to the given delay to allow other records to be sent so that the sends can be batched together
#linger.ms=

# the maximum size of a request in bytes
#max.request.size=

# the default batch size in bytes when batching multiple records sent to a partition
#batch.size=

# the total bytes of memory the producer can use to buffer records waiting to be sent to the server
#buffer.memory=
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
```

logs

```
DEBUG:kafka.client:Node bootstrap-0 connected
DEBUG:kafka.client:Sending metadata request MetadataRequest_v1(topics=['testexample']) to node bootstrap-0
DEBUG:kafka.protocol.parser:Sending request MetadataRequest_v1(topics=['testexample'])
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=xxx:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('xxx', 9092)]> Request 1: MetadataRequest_v1(topics=['testexample'])
ERROR:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=xxx:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('xxx', 9092)]>: socket disconnected
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=xxx:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('xxx', 9092)]>: Closing connection. KafkaConnectionError: socket disconnected
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=xxx:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('xxx', 9092)]>: reconnect backoff 0.046982738338269325 after 1 failures
DEBUG:kafka.producer.kafka:_wait_on_metadata woke after 59.79792523384094 secs.
DEBUG:kafka.producer.kafka:Requesting metadata update for topic testexample
DEBUG:kafka.client:Initializing connection to node bootstrap-0 for metadata request
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=xxx:9092 <disconnected> [IPv4 ('xxx', 9092)]>: creating new socket
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=xxx:9092 <disconnected> [IPv4 ('xxx', 9092)]>: setting socket option (6, 1, 1)
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=xxx:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('xxx', 9092)]>: connecting to xxx:9092 [('xxx', 9092) IPv4]
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=xxx:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('xxx', 9092)]>: established TCP connection
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=xxx:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('xxx', 9092)]>: Connection complete.
DEBUG:kafka.client:Node bootstrap-0 connected
DEBUG:kafka.client:Sending metadata request MetadataRequest_v1(topics=['testexample']) to node bootstrap-0
DEBUG:kafka.protocol.parser:Sending request MetadataRequest_v1(topics=['testexample'])
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=xxx:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('xxx', 9092)]> Request 1: MetadataRequest_v1(topics=['testexample'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "producer.py", line 11, in <module>
    producer.send('testexample', {'key': 'value'})
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kafka/producer/kafka.py", line 564, in send
    self._wait_on_metadata(topic, self.config['max_block_ms'] / 1000.0)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kafka/producer/kafka.py", line 691, in _wait_on_metadata
    "Failed to update metadata after %.1f secs." % (max_wait,))
kafka.errors.KafkaTimeoutError: KafkaTimeoutError: Failed to update metadata after 60.0 secs.
INFO:kafka.producer.kafka:Closing the Kafka producer with 0 secs timeout.
INFO:kafka.producer.kafka:Proceeding to force close the producer since pending requests could not be completed within timeout 0.
DEBUG:kafka.producer.sender:Beginning shutdown of Kafka producer I/O thread, sending remaining records.
INFO:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=xxx:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('xxx', 9092)]>: Closing connection. 
DEBUG:kafka.conn:<BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=xxx:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('xxx', 9092)]>: reconnect backoff 0.0579924217995576 after 1 failures
DEBUG:kafka.producer.sender:Shutdown of Kafka producer I/O thread has completed.
DEBUG:kafka.producer.kafka:The Kafka producer has closed.
INFO:kafka.producer.kafka:Kafka producer closed
```

Comment: Can you set log levels to `DEBUG` and share the full error trace?

Comment: hi @GiorgosMyrianthous please see above

Comment: Also, can you share the full content of `server.properties`?

Comment: have shared as above

Comment: `bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092` is this correct?

Comment: it worked when i tried the below /opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list <internal-ip>:9092 --producer.config /opt/bitnami/kafka/conf/producer.properties --topic testexample

/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server <internal-ip>:9092 --topic testexample --consumer.config /opt/bitnami/kafka/conf/consumer.properties --from-beginning

Comment: Then why did you use localhost:9092 instead of your internal Ip?

Comment: the config was defaulted when i downloaded the bitnami vm onto aws and I didnt change any config. In any case even if i placed in my public ip of my ec2 instance into the producer, it still doesnt work.